# How to avoid mutating table error while using a trigger?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I need to insert rows in a `Table_A`, with values from `Table_B` on UPDATE of `Table_B`.

```sql
table_A (
station int,
state   varchar(20),
CONSTRAINT pk_table_a PRIMARY KEY(station, state),
CONSTRAINT fk_table_A FOREIGN KEY (station, state)
    REFERENCES table_B (station, state)
)

table_B (
station int,
state   varchar(20),
player  int,
date_sent Date DEFAULT NULL
CONSTRAINT pk_table_b PRIMARY KEY(station, state, player)
)
```

Now, my triggers needs to add a row to `table_A (station, state)`, when all the dates for these `(station, state)` become `NOT NULL` in `table_B`.

Here's my actual which causes `mutating table error`:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER add_stations_sent
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON "TABLE_B"
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (NEW.DATE_SENT IS NOT NULL)
DECLARE
    nb_stations_null number;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(1)
    INTO nbr_stations_null
    FROM "TABLE_B"
    WHERE "TABLE_B".STATE = :NEW.STATE AND
          "TABLE_B".STATION <> :NEW.STATION AND
          "TABLE_B".DATE_SENT IS NULL;

    IF (nb_stations_null = 0) THEN
        INSERT INTO "TABLE_A" VALUES (:NEW.STATION, :NEW.STATE);
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: use a [compound trigger](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/trigger-enhancements-11gr1#compound_triggers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will defer the processing to AFTER STATEMENT level and thus allow to you run queries

```
create or replace 
trigger avoid_mutate
for insert or update on table_b
compound trigger

  l_station sys.odcivarchar2list := sys.odcivarchar2list();
  l_state   sys.odcivarchar2list := sys.odcivarchar2list();

  before each row is
  begin
    l_station.extend;
    l_state.extend;
    l_station(l_station.count) := :new.station;
    l_state(l_state.count)     := :new.state;
  end before each row;

  after statement is
  declare
    nb_stations_null number;
  begin
    for i in 1 .. l_station.count loop
      SELECT COUNT(1)
      INTO nbr_stations_null
      FROM "TABLE_B"
      WHERE "TABLE_B".STATE = l_state(i) AND
            "TABLE_B".STATION <> l_station(i) AND
            "TABLE_B".DATE_SENT IS NULL;    
            
    IF (nb_stations_null = 0) THEN
        INSERT INTO "TABLE_A" VALUES (l_station(i), l_state(i));
    END IF;
    
  end after statement;

end;
/
```